# Using background-size with relative height

Tags: css

How to set a background of an div container by only giving it a relative height (no content in the div besides the background itself).

The code below works fine, but it gives my div an absolute hight of 350px.
When ever i rescale the browser window, there will be an gap between the div and the content which follows after it by 350px.

```
#div 
{
background: url("bg.jpg") no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
height: 350px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: So don't give the element an explicit height?

Comment: So you want the `#div` to not affect formatting?

Comment: The background image won't be displayed if I don't give a height.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Now I understand.  I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the div to have the full height, make the div, html, and body have a height of `100%` with no margin to fill the full screen:

```
html, body, #div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Then, set the background to cover without overflow:

```
#div {
    background: url("http://placehold.it/350x150") no-repeat center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: none;
}
```

**Fiddle**: <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6H2AQ/1/)</kbd>

This positions the background in the center horizontally, cutting off any left or right overflow.

*This also assumes that your background is longer horizontally than it is vertically, which it sounds like from your question.  If not, you should fix the background and center it vertically as well.*

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

You can also add the following for different device width

```
.responsive-image{
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
} 


/* Retina display */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
   .responsive-image{
    background-image: url('../img/retina.jpg');
    }
}
/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1024px){
   .responsive-image{
    background-image: url('../img/desktop.jpg');
    }
}
/* Tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 980px){
    .responsive-image{
    background-image: url('../img/tablet.jpg');
    }
}
/* Mobile HD */
@media screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 760px){
    .responsive-image{
    background-image: url('../img/mobile-hd.jpg');
    }
}
/* Mobile LD */
@media screen and (max-width: 350px){
    .responsive-image{
    background-image: url('../img/mobile-ld.jpg');
    }
}
```